# Python - Regex - findall duplicates

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm trying to match e-mails in html text using the following code in python

```
my_second_pat = '((\w+)( *?))(@|[aA][tT]|\([aA][tT]\))(((( *?)(\w+)( *?))(\.|[dD][oO][tT]|\([dD][oO][tT]\)))+)([eE][dD][uU]|[cC][oO][mM])'


matches = re.findall(my_second_pat,line)
for m in matches:
    s = "".join(m)
    email = "".join(s.split())
    res.append((name,'e',email))
```

when I run it on a `line = shoham@stanford.edu`

I get:

```
[('shoham', 'shoham', '', '@', 'stanford.', 'stanford.', 'stanford', '', 'stanford', '', '.', 'edu')]
```

what I expect:

```
[('shoham','@', 'stanford.', 'edu')]
```

It's matched as a one string on regexpal.com, so I guess I'm having trouble with `re.findall`

I'm new to both regex, and python. Any optimization/modifications is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?i)([^@\s]{2,})(?:@|\s*at\s*)([^@\s.]{2,})(?:\.|\s*dot\s*)([^@\s.]{2,})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/w7cDbycw71VO6aEq)

If you need to limit to `.com` and `.edu`:

```
(?i)([^@\s]{2,})(?:@|\s*at\s*)([^@\s.]{2,})(?:\.|\s*dot\s*)(com|edu)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gj5buG9fdS-UJQHu)

Note that I have used the case-insensitive flag `(?i)` at the start of the regex, instead of using syntax like `[Ee]`.

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is matching all of your capture groups, which contain optional matches.

---

#### Try this:

```
((?:(?:\w+)(?: *?))(?:@|[aA][tT]|\(?:[aA][tT]\))(?:(?:(?:(?: *?)(?:\w+)(?: *?))(?:\.|[dD][oO][tT]|\(?:[dD][oO][tT]\)))+)(?:[eE][dD][uU]|[cC][oO][mM]))
```

---

#### See this link to debug your expression:

> http://regex101.com/r/jW4mP1